# Django Admin list_filter not showing

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

So this is my code:

```
class Destino(models.Model):
    paisid = models.IntegerField(blank = True,null = True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    grupo = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True, null = True)
    requisitos_turismo = models.ManyToManyField(Requisito, related_name = "requisitos_turismo", blank = True)
    requisitos_negocios = models.ManyToManyField(Requisito, related_name = "requisitos_negocios", blank = True)
    dias_min_entrada = models.IntegerField(blank = True,null=True)
    importancia = models.CharField(max_length = 200, default = "15")
    enlace = models.CharField(max_length = 200,blank = True,null = True)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to="img", null = True,blank = True)
    # formulario = models.ForeignKey('Formulario', related_name = "destino_formulario", blank = True,null = True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre


class Tasa(models.Model):
    nacionalidad = models.ForeignKey(Destino, related_name = "nationality")
    destino = models.ForeignKey(Destino, related_name = "destination")
    duracion_dias = models.IntegerField(blank = True,null = True)
    tipo_visado = models.ForeignKey(TipoVisado, blank = True,null = True)
    motivo = models.ForeignKey(Motivo, blank = True, null = True)
    precio = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 6, decimal_places = 2, blank = True, null = True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s" % (self.nacionalidad.nombre,self.destino.nombre,str(self.duracion_dias),self.motivo.nombre,self.tipo_visado.nombre,self.precio)

class AdminTasas(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['nacionalidad__enlace']
    ordering = ('nacionalidad__enlace',)
    list_filter = (
        ('destino', admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter),
    )

admin.site.register(Tasa,AdminTasas)
```

I`m trying to add an admin filter to the Tasa model
but the filter it doesnt show on the admin

if i change the filter from "destino" to "nacionalidad" [ is the same main model("Destino") ] , i get the filter on the admin , and working ,with the list of all countries.
Any king of help will be really apreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just found the solution . You need to have more than 1 "destinos" to show the list_filter.

Comment: WOW thanks! Had this issue today. Really unexpected behaviour, but makes sense.

Comment: that's very confusing. Is this behaviour documented?

Comment: today I had a different issue on the same topic. if you have a custom filter an if you return empty list instead of `[(None, None)]` on `lookups` it doesn't show.